# VACUUM is taking a lot of time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

The following command `VACUUM my_table` has been running for 24 hours already on Postgres (v11.5)

The table has around:

- 112 million rows
- Table Space: 193 GB
- 6 indexes on 6 different fields + Primary Key index

Is this normal?

More information if it helps...

- AWS RDS instance
- 16GB memory + 4 vCPU (db.m5.xlarge)
- 800GB allocated storage (Database is taking 495GB of that so far)
- Provisioned IOPS - 10000

Adding more info here -

- `SELECT relname, n_dead_tup FROM pg_stat_user_tables;` returns `163441017`
- We are not running any application queries against the DB, we wanted to let the DB finish vacuum process

Comment: This might be better asked on the sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: What does `select * from pg_stat_progress_vacuum` show?

Comment: @jjanes it shows phase=`scanning heap`

Answer (score 1):

It can be. Maybe your 16GB RAM is too low for effective manipulation with big tables (190GB). Very generic rule says so RAM should be about 1/10 db size.

What you can check:

a) look to table `pg_stat_activity` for related process and check if `vacuum` is not in waiting on lock state.

b) if you can, check metrics related to IO. Maybe there you will see high IO waits - this is signal, so your IO is overloaded, and then `vacuum` can be very slow. Table 193GB is really big.

Comment: The state of vacuum process is now "scanning heap", it was "vacuuming indexes" earlier. So things are moving. In terms IO metrics, it has generally been low, so that doesn't seem like a bottleneck.